# File Picker on Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

There is a library for create a simple file picker that not use an app on the phone?
For example if i want get a file like doc or txt it's impossible use an app with the MozActivity so it's needed a custom way.
For example in my app https://github.com/Mte90/RingTone-Picker-for-FirefoxOS i have created a list that filter the file extension. I think that a solution like a mini file manager it's better.
Many people ask me a file picker but i have no idea for a simple solution for all the problems.

Comment: Do you mean you want a app which provides a WebActivity resource to pick files from sdcard?

Comment: I want a function or class that open a file picker and return the filename with the path (and the blob if required). 
Like a classic file picker (that navigate in the system or sd card) in the browser.

Comment: There is none AFAIK. But should not be hard to create one using `enumerate` of the `DeviceStorage` API.

Answer (score 2):

Give this library a try:

- [FinderJS](https://github.com/applait/finderjs)

We built it for our organization realizing that we need to use this for other projects as well.

Cheers!

Update: The app mentioned is now live in the Firefox Marketplace. It is called [Finder](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/finder).

Comment: some chance for an interactive example like in the gh-pages branch?

Comment: I'm building an app which uses this. I should be able to share the code in a couple of days :-)