# how easy choose file(image) from device or sdcard in firefox os

Tags: storage, firefox-os

How I need choose image from sdcard or device, and save path for it(set to input).
Exist any api or something fow choose image in firefox os?

Thanks

Comment: Check that discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527190/file-picker-on-firefox-os

Comment: Yea I looked at it. I tried FinderJS but i dont undestand how i can find all files of images type(jpg, png..(maybe jpg will be enough)
If I understand its depend on argument searchterm: `finder.search(searchterm);`. I try "*.*" but result in debug was empty or searchComplete Array [ "*.*", 0 ]
If I try search exist image (in firefox profile fake-card) using
 ` finder.on("fileFound", function (file, fileinfo, storageName) {
                console.log("Found file " + fileinfo.name + " at " + fileinfo.path + " in " + storageName, file);
            });`
its not call. How i show/write all images?

Comment: uhm ask to their github repo for that

Comment: And where can I do it here https://github.com/applait/finderjs ? Any chat/forum?

Comment: on issues of the github repo